# Maximum time for a request with HttpWebRequest/Invoke-WebRequest?

Tags: .net, powershell

I have fiddled around with both System.Net.HttpWebRequest and Invoke-WebRequest (I know that beneath it is the same code) and both gives a 500 status in the following scenario:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=270000' -TimeoutSec 360000
```

How can this be? httpstat.us is clearly set to only wait for 4.5 min. and the timeout is way above that, but all I get is a:

> Invoke-WebRequest : 500 - The request timed out.
>   The web server failed to respond within the specified time.
>   At line:1 char:13
>   + $response = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=270000'  ...
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
>      eption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

It seems to me, that there's a maximum timeout of the request (about 3-4 min.). Anobody knows what to do?

I have set up this scenario because I have a website that I need to test that has a long response time.

Comment: This is a problem with httpstat.us, as you can see if you browse to https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=270000 and wait a few minutes. Apparently the maximum timeout is less than the 5 minutes that they claim on the main site.

Comment: Thanks @Blorgbeard for the answer. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Blogrbeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369/blorgbeard) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

**It is https://httpstat.us itself that is unexpectedly timing out**, because, as of this writing, **the *actual* max. sleep time appears to be 3 mins. and 50 seconds** (230 secs., i.e., in ms., as part of the query string: `?sleep=230000`), not the 5 mins. *documented*.
`?sleep=270000` - 4.5 mins. - is therefore too high a value.

Therefore, `Invoke-WebRequest` is blameless here - its `-TimeoutSecs` value never comes into play, and even omitting `-TimeoutSecs` altogether (i.e., specifying no timeout at all) would yield the same result:

```
PS> (Measure-Command { 
      Invoke-WebRequest https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=270000  2>&1 | Out-Default 
     }).TotalSeconds

Invoke-WebRequest : 500 - The request timed out. ...
...
230.57306
```

*Update*: As it [turns out](https://github.com/Readify/httpstatus/issues/44), **it is *Azure* - where https://httpstat.usis being hosted as of this writing - that is imposing the 230-second limit**:

> When using the hosted instance the timeout is actually 230 seconds, which is the max timeout allowed by an Azure WebApp (see [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05f254a6-9b34-4eb2-a5f7-2a82fb40135f/time-out-after-230-seconds?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)).
>   If you host it yourself in IIS/IIS Express you won't have that limit.